# Forcing miller to read data as string in conversion to JSON

Tags: json, miller

In the following MWE

```
echo x="1e2" | mlr --ojson cat
```

my intention is for miller to generate a one-element JSON array containing the object

```
{"x": "1e2"}
```

The object actually returned (within the array) is instead

```
{"x": 1e2}
```

where the value is taken as a number, I guess that as a consequence of its parsing. How can I tell miller to generate the JSON object with a string for its value rather than a number? (The rationale underlying the quotation marks around '1e2' in the MWE is precisely to highlight this intention.)

Comment: In `echo x="1e2"`, do you think the output includes the quotes?

Comment: @muru: I get your point. I was only highlighting my intention to have as value a string rather than a number. Escaping the quotation marks would lead to a string value, but one including the latter (escaped) marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Miller 6 you can use [`-S` flag](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/new-in-miller-6/#type-inference), which forces Miller to treat the data as strings:

```
echo x="1e2" | mlr --ojson -S cat
```

to get

```
[
{
  "x": "1e2"
}
]
```

Or you can cast it using `string` function

```
echo x="1e2" | mlr --ojson put '$x=string($x)'
```